# Accessing ruby controller from another controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm making a dashboard with RoR, the dashboard is going to show a list of projects to a logged in user.

The dashboard will be within a single page context. The dashboard itself has a controller and there is a separate controller for the projects.

When I make a request to the dashboard it is processed by the dashboard controllers index action. I would like to be able to print out a list of projects. These projects are returned from a `getAll` method on the project controller.

The project controller requires the context of a user so that it can correctly match a user with their projects. I have tried exporting the projects as an
`@projects` instance variable within the `getAll` projects method, however as the dashboard controller is what is being called and not the project controller then this variable is not in scope, or initialized.

I was planning to display the projects in the view by using a partial for the    `@projects` collection. It appears that I also can't call this via AJAX as it requires the user's session.

What would be the best way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the dashboard controller use a method like this

```
def getprojects
@projects=Project.all
end
```

If you want the specific user's projects then

```
   def getprojects
   @projects=Project.where(:user_id=>params[:user_id])
   end
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you don't want to repeat the logic,then change the routes so it accesses the project controller directly

Comment: Assuming the Project class you are referring to is the model, would this cause a duplicate of logic where the projects are selected in both the dashboard controller, and also the project controller?

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the logic,then change the routes so it accesses the project controller directly

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this by declaring a static version of the `getAll` method which in turn calls the non-static version. The static version takes the user session as a parameter which can then be used in the non-static method.

Static version of the method is available from the Dashboard Controller where the user session is passed in.